# How to monitor GlusterFS clients?

Tags: glusterfs, system-monitoring, glusterfs-3.5

We are doing Ok (we'd like to think) monitoring our GlusterFS *servers* via Icinga. We'd like to monitor the *clients* too.

Other than making sure, there is a `glusterfs` process running for each `glusterfs`-entry in `/etc/fstab`, what else can be done? We'd like to avoid superficial reads/writes on the mounted volumes, if possible -- can the health of a mount be monitored without adding additional loads, however small?

Any other thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: what about using a custom  SNMP MIB ?  fetching information out of the logs maybe ?

Comment: What will populate the SNMP information? I'm not asking for monitoring framework -- we have one already. I'm wondering, _what_ to look for -- not _how_. Information from logs? Anything in particular I should look for? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you say I'd avoid to actually access the volume to verify its availability because in case of failure I'd have a process stuck in interruptible state (the check itself).

The glusterfs process should be in a valid state (i.e. not Zombie), and the mountpoint should be properly listed in `/proc/mounts` and/or `/etc/mtab`. You may want to check that the GlusterFS servers are reachable by the clients (i.e., no firewall rules are blocking them).

Some sort of (client) log analysis could give you even more insight, but I have no patterns to suggest.

The tools on [GlusterForge](https://forge.gluster.org) seems to be mostly server-oriented:

- https://forge.gluster.org/gstatus/pages/Home
- https://forge.gluster.org/nagios-monitoring